# input.ssml` is longer than the limit of 5000 bytes"

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-text-to-speech, ssml

I am trying to generate audio from `ssml` file using google text-to-speech. For this purpose I am using `@google-cloud/text-to-speech` NPM package. It is throwing error like

> input.ssml is longer than the limit of 5000 bytes.

**The code**

```
const client = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient()


        const request = {
            input: { ssml: fs.readFileSync(ssmlFilePathLocal).toString() },
            voice: { languageCode: tempLanguage.pollyLanguageCode, ssmlGender: ssmlGender },
            audioConfig: { audioEncoding: 'MP3' },
        }
        
        const [response] = await client.synthesizeSpeech(request)
```

Can anyone help me out to achieve my result using google text to speech?

I can not use `TextToSpeechLongAudioSynthesizeClient` as it is not allowing `ssml` as input.